# Batch copy files from different folders based on Date LOOP

Tags: windows, batch-file

I hope someone can help me.

**Suppose you have the following folder:**
*(Where YYYYMMDD indicates the folder name)*
C:\folder\20160101
C:\folder\20160102
C:\folder\20160203
... until the
C:\folder\20160231

**Inside the folders are there any file sort by code for example:**
XXX0001
XXX0002
XXX0003

I would like to create a batch file that according to three manually set variables
CODE: XXX0001
DATA FROM = for example 20160101
DATE UP = for example 20160131

**I want to move all files with the dates entered from Folder Input to Folder Output.
I created a good part of the script, but I'm stuck for the loop.**

How can I do?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls
set CODICE=
set /P CODICE=Insert code: %=%

set DATADA=
set /P DATADA=Insert Date[AAAAMMGG es (20160303)]: %=%

set DATAFINE=
set /P DATAFINE=Insert Data [AAAAMMGG es (20160306)]: %=%


set /A DATASOTTR=%DATAFINE%-%DATADA% 


FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,%DATASOTTR%) DO (..... AND NOW??)

REM copy /-y \input\%DATA%\%CODICE% c:\output
```

Comment: I would use a VB/JS script or PS as looping dates is going to be a pain.

Comment: @AlexK. Normally I think "You should use Powershell" comments aren't helping much, but for once I totally agree with you.